# Can a calculated or renamed column be used in the same select statement (without using a subquery)

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql-9.1

Can the following statement be made to work?:

```
SELECT
id AS "ID",
unnest(agent_ids) AS "AgentID",
idtotitle('users', "AgentID") AS "AgentName", -- lookup agent name
from users;
```

> ERROR:  column "AgentID" does not exist  LINE 4:  idtotitle('users',
>   "AgentID") AS "AgentName"

Seems to telling me that the unnested column value can't be referenced in the same statement. I could wrap the whole thing in a subselect but since the statement is being generated by existing code that doesn't support the sub-select syntax I'd prefer to avoid that if possible.

I'm also curious why the above doesn't work in the first place.

EDIT: Not specific to unnest(), this fails too:

```
SELECT
id AS "UserID",
'User ' || "UserID" AS "UserName" 
FROM users;
```

> ERROR: column "UserID" does not exist

So you can't access columns you create / rename in the same statement?

Comment: The only way to access the alias is to use a derived table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You already know the solution -- use a subquery, CTE, or repeat the expression.

The reason is simple.  The SQL standard does not specify the order of evaluation of expressions in the `select` clause.  You might think it logical that they be processed as written, from left to right, but the powers that define SQL never mandated this.

Hence, the expression that uses the column alias could be evaluated prior to the expression that defines it -- leading to the problem.  To prevent this, SQL engines do not allow you to use a column alias at the same level it is defined.

Comment: Yes left-to-right evaluation did seem logical to me.

Comment: *"To prevent this, SQL engines do not allow you to use a column alias at the same level it is defined."* - There's nothing technical that keeps SQL engines from analysing the AST of the `SELECT` clause in order to determine a strict evaluation order, if there are no cycles - apart from incompatibilities that might be introduced when ambiguities arise

Comment: @LukasEder . . . What seems logical for the query gets much more complicated when you have expressions with aggregation functions, subqueries in the `select`,  and read operations that process some (but perhaps not all) expressions.  The folks who write the standard are quite aware that the behavior is counterintuitive, but sequential evaluation cause problems both in the execution engine and in the interpretation of columns.  For instance, the order of expressions in the `select` doesn't matter; the values are always the same.  This would not be true with sequential evaluation.

Comment: I think it's all a matter of proper scope definition, regardless if you have correlated subqueries or other types of "complex" expressions. From then on implementations may choose to expand/transform expressions or store them in variables. Yes, the standard text would get (even) more complicated. But it could probably be done...

Comment: ... in any case, no matter what we conclude, it's currently not possible :-)

Answer (score 1):

Interestingly, you cannot reuse column aliases that you're declaring in the `SELECT` clause in that same `SELECT` clause. Technically, there is no reason for this feature to be missing. Databases could detect the reference dependency graph and check for cycles, and allow non-cyclic references, but that's simply not possible in most databases (there are some databases that allow for some "same-scope-column-referencing", specifically when window functions are involved).

Here's an overview over what's possible in PostgreSQL:

#### Can't reference column alias declared in same `SELECT` scope:

```
select 1 as "ID", "ID" + 1;       -- This would be very useful but isn't possible
select 1 as "ID" where "ID" = 1;  -- This would be very useful but isn't possible
select 1 as "ID" having "ID" = 1; -- This doesn't even make sense
```

#### Can reference column alias declared in same `SELECT` scope:

```
select 1 as "ID" group by "ID";   -- Only few databases allow this
select 1 as "ID" order by "ID";   -- This is explicitly allowed by the SQL standard
```

So, as others have mentioned, with respect to your question, you'll have to resort to generating your calculated values in a table, e.g. a common table expression, or a derived table.